# Get geoJSON data from mapbox API to determine point in polygon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I recently followed this tutorial to determine if a point shown by a marker sits inside a defined polygon: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/point-in-polygon/

Works great, but they pull in the polygon geoJSON data with ajax and apply it to the map. I have a mapbox map already built with a polygon area drawn. I'm using their API to display my map. I now need to access the geoJSON data to determine if a point is within an area. How can I access that data through the API?

Here's how I pull in the map, the geoJSON and a function to test if a point is in a geoJSON area:

```
//mapbox connection
var mapID = "<map-id>";
L.mapbox.accessToken = "<my-token>";

//init map
var map = L.mapbox.map("mapData", mapID, {
  attributionControl: false, 
  zoomControl: false
}).setView([53.799, -1.548], 13, {
  pan: { animate: true },
  zoom: { animate: true } 
});

//get geoJSON
var geoJson;
$http.get("https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/" + mapID + "/features.json?access_token=" + L.mapbox.accessToken).success(function(data){
  geoJson = data;
});

//determine point in polygon
function determinePointInPolygon(){
  var coords = [-1.3, 5.2];
  var layer = leafletPip.pointInLayer(coords, L.geoJson(geoJson), true);
  if (!layer.length) //point not in polygon
  else //point is in polygon
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: You say you already have a polygon. Do you know its coordinates? In what format are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrated features are loaded into a `L.mapbox.featureLayer` which is available as a member of your `L.mapbox.Map` instance. Let's say you have your map instance stored in a reference called `map` your layer would be `map.featureLayer`:

```
// Make sure the featureLayer is ready
map.featureLayer.on('ready', function (e) {
    // Loop over the features
    e.target.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        // Do your thing
        // here "layer" holds an instance of the marker/polygon/polyline
        // "layer.feature" holds the actual geojson feature
    });
});
```

Here's an example of the concept: http://plnkr.co/edit/D5IfRTLV0yXTqOmzNCYA?p=preview

You could also load the tiles and features seperately if you wish, instanciate your map with no `mapid`:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', null, {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 1
});

var tileLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('yourMapId').addTo(map);

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('yourMapId').addTo(map);
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/9pYeRu6UmxuVL1TLzwPR?p=preview

Then you could leave out the `addTo` method, first process your features and then add the layer to the map:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('yourMapId');
// Make sure the featureLayer is ready
featureLayer.on('ready', function (e) {
    // Loop over the features
    e.target.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        // Do your thing
    });
    // Add layer to the map
    e.target.addTo(map);
});
```

What ever works best for you. But i almost forgot to actually answer your question (although i think you won't be needing this anymore), the actual GeoJSON featurecollection can be obtained by using `L.mapbox.FeatureLayer`'s `getGeoJSON` method (only when the layer is ready ofcourse):

```
// Make sure the featureLayer is ready
featureLayer.on('ready', function (e) {
    // Fetch you featurecollection
    var geojson = e.target.getGeoJSON();
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a go (although I'm not using jQuery)

Comment: Erhmz?!, How do you come to the conclusion that you need jQuery? because of the `on` method? that's native to `L.mapbox.featureLayer`, no jQuery needed. I've added another way of adding the featureLayer to the map. Maybe that will be handier for you

Comment: Think I'm almost here with this but a bit confused. The `layer` variable created in the `eachLayer` function doesn't seem to be the geoJSON data I was expecting. I need to run the geoJSON (as a variable) through this: `leafletPip.pointInLayer(coords, L.geoJson(geoJson), true);`

Comment: The `layer` object which is returned by the `eachLayer` method has a member property called `feature` which holds the actual geojson featureobject. So you'll need `layer.feature.geometry.coordinates`. I'll edit my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Ok, slightly misunderstood what you we're doing, but i see you've got it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the JSON somewhere else when you pull it in:

First define an object where you want to store it somewehre globally:

```
var geoJSON;
```

Then when you pull it in, just define it with the data

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mapbox.js/assets/data/us-states.geojson',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function load(d) {
        geoJSON = d; // THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED
        var states = L.geoJson(d).addTo(map);
        L.marker([38, -102], {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                'marker-color': '#f86767'
            }),
            draggable: true
        }).addTo(map)
        .on('dragend', function(e) {
            var layer = leafletPip.pointInLayer(this.getLatLng(), states, true);
            if (layer.length) {
              state.innerHTML = '<strong>' + layer[0].feature.properties.name + '</strong>';
            } else {
              state.innerHTML = '';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific in my question. I drew the polygon onto my map in Mapbox (through their website interface). The polygon is therefore saved as part of the map. I display the map using the mapbox API. This of course also shows the polygon. Now I want to access the polygon data without having to do another ajax call to mapbox. I'll update my question.

Comment: You only did one call, you just used the data it already returned multiple times.

Comment: I've updated my question to show the full method I'm currently doing. I'm currently having to do a second ajax call directly to mapbox to get the geoJSON which I don't want to do.

Comment: Yeh I know but I've already loaded the mapbox.js script and displayed my map (with the polygon) using the mapbox API. Therefore, all map data should be accessible through the object `L.mapbox`. How come I then have to do this ajax call to get the geoJSON separately?